# Quadratic equation-condition for positiveness

Tags: derivatives

what is the condition for the positiveness of the quadratic function $A u+B u^2+C u^3$ is always positive for all $0<u<1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an elementary take on the problem, certainly rudimental, but an answer nevertheless.
One writes $$ Au + Bu^2 + Cu^3 = u (A+ Bu + Cu^2) $$ and concludes that, in order to fullfill the positiveness condition, the quadratic expression $$ A+ Bu + Cu^2 $$ must not have roots in the interval $[0, 1]$ (an passant,  $A> 0$, as it is the value of the polynomial for $u=0$).

If $$ \Delta = B^2 – 4AC < 0$$ the roots are both imaginary, so no problem.
If $$ \Delta B^2 – 4AC \geq  0$$ then the following conditions applies

$$\bigg[ \frac{+B + \sqrt {\Delta}}{2C} < 0 \,\,\ OR \,\,\ \frac{+B - \sqrt {\Delta}}{2C}  > 1 \bigg] $$
OR
$$\bigg[ \frac{+B + \sqrt {\Delta}}{2C} > 1 \,\,\ AND \,\,\ \frac{+B - \sqrt {\Delta}}{2C}  < 0  \bigg] $$

(larger root less than zero OR smaller root greater than 1) OR (larger root greater than 1 AND smaller root less than 0)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: it must be $$Au+Bu^2+Cu^3>0$$ this is equivalent to
$$C\left(u+\frac {B}{2C}\right)^2+\frac{4AC-B^2}{4C}>0$$
this is fulfilled if $$C>0$$ and $$4AC-B^2>0$$ for all $u$ with $0<u<1$

Comment: Wouldn't these conditions give $f(u) > 0$ for all $u > 0$? All that is required is $f(u) > 0$ for $u \in (0,1)$. So it should be acceptable if $f$ has a root outside of this interval.